# Is the Evasiveness Conjecture strong enough to constructively imply the negation of the Pizzazz-conjecture?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, simplicial-complexes

**Question.** Assume the truth of the (notoriously open)  [Evasiveness Conjecture](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895600920008). Does this constructively imply the [negation of the Pizzazz-conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/283180)?

**Remarks.**

- The relevant statements are, by themselves, so natural, and transparently explained in the links given, that repeating them here seems superfluous. In particular, let

> 'Pizzazz-conjecture'$\equiv$'The graph-property $\mathcal{P}_{n,d}$ of all those graphs on $n$ which admit of a faithful orthogonal representation in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space is monotone-decreasing.'

- The adverb 'constructively' in the question-statement is not precisely-defined. You may substitute it with 'reasonably' or 'appreciably'.
- This question was motivated by an embarassing gaffe of mine in the thread cited above (a fallacious proof by contradiction of the negation of the Pizzazz-conjecture). It still seems to me that there should be

> an *easy argument* why Pizzazz' $\mathcal{P}_{n,d}$ cannot possibly be monotone; assuming EC should strong be enough a tool to give a good argument.

- Needless to say, this is all about whether there is *good argument* why the property defined by Pizzazz cannot possibly be evasive. I.e., can one be always be sure to have a representable graph *before* the last edge has been uncovered?